# Cannot read property 'seek' of undefined

Tags: react-native, react-native-video

I'm trying to use the react-native-video component as follows:

```
export default class VideoWrapper extends Component<Props> {

  render() {
    return (
        <Video
          source={require('../../assets/test_sound.mp3')}
          ref={player => {
            this.player = player;
          }}
          muted={false}
          repeat={false}
          resizeMode={"cover"}
          volume={1.0}
          rate={1.0}
          ignoreSilentSwitch={"obey"}
          onProgress={this.onProgress}
          onSeek={this.onSeek}
          onEnd={this.onEnd}
          onError={this.onError} 
        />
    );
  }
  onEnd() {
    this.player.seek(0);
  }
  ...
```

Results in:

> ExceptionsManager.js:74 Cannot read property 'seek' of undefined

If I change the onEnd method to the following it works:

```
onEnd={ () => this.player.seek(0) }
```

I don't want to use this second approach because it is cluttering up my xml code.  How can I fix the first approach?

Comment: Have you tried `onEnd() {
    if (this.player) this.player.seek(0);
  }` ?

Comment: Yes.  `this.player` is never set, so the seek never happens.

Comment: you bind your `onEnd` method in the constrcutor ?? or did you try to convert it in to an arrow function to get `this` context ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
onEnd = () => {
    this.player.seek(0);
  };
```